# useEffect and setState on async backend calls not re-rendering component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

We have a cardList react native component that is a child of search component.

```
export default function CardList(props) {

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
      <ListItem
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={item.subtitle}
        leftAvatar={{
          source: item.avatar_url && { uri: item.avatar_url },
          title: item.name[0]
        }}
        bottomDivider
        chevron
      />
  )

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      data={props.images}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  );
}
```

The Search fetches data async from backend which takes a couple of seconds and is done with useEffect, for some reason the setKeys in useEffect does not re-render the cardList component. When I refresh artificially with hot-reload on expo the cardList renders fine. Why does setKeys (useState) not render the component?

Thanks for any help!

```
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const imgkeys = await << 5 second long backend call >>;
      setKeys(imgkeys);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{
        padding: 5,
         }}>  
        { (keys) && (keys.length>0) && <CardList images={keys}/> }
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

setState is asynchronous for performance reasons and shouldn't be forced to be synchronous just because state updates weren't performed correctly.

You can simply define the useState like that:

```
const [, forceUpdate] = React.useState(0);
forceUpdate(n => !n)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?